# Determining whether an $m \times n$ matrix is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Given this matrix, I am supposed to determine whether multiplication by $A$ is a one-to-one matrix transformation. I know that if this was an $n \times n$ matrix I could discover if it was one-to-one by checking its determinant but I don't understand how to do it for an $m \times n$.

I read that it was something about if the matrix had the property $m \ge n$ but I don't see how this applies. Thank you for any help.

Comment: A matrix provides an injective linear transformation if and only if its kernel is trivial.

Comment: A matrix of $n\times m$, $m \neq n$ can't be injective. We can find *pseudoinverses* which give unique outputs but those unique outputs fulfil some extra constraint such as for example minimizing the norm or mean squared error whereas exact solutions are more than one or don't exist.

Comment: @mathreadler If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then the mapping $x \mapsto Ax$ is injective.  This can happen for rectangular matrices with fewer columns than rows.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$
T = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Show that in the equation $$T \bf{x} = 0 \iff \bf{x}=0$$

i.e., the trivial solution is the only one that solves this.

Comment: So I would change the matrix into it's equation form and then solve for x?

Comment: Yes, set $ x = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})^T$ and try to solve four equations in four unknowns.

Answer (score 2):

The condition is that all $3\times3$ subdeterminants are not all $0$. If you know about exterior powers, this means the exterior power $\stackrel{3}{\bigwedge}A\ne 0$.

More generally, if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, representing a linear map $\varphi\colon\mathbf R^n\longrightarrow\mathbf R^m$, the condition is that the $n$-th exterior power of this map:
$$\stackrel{n}{\bigwedge}\varphi\colon\stackrel{n}{\bigwedge}\mathbf R^n\simeq\mathbf R\longrightarrow\stackrel{n}{\bigwedge}\mathbf R^m\simeq\mathbf R^{\binom mn}$$
is injective, i.e. non-zero.

In terms of matrices,, this means the minors of order $n$ are not all $0$.

*Note* : This is valid for vector spaces over any field.

There is also an extension for `finitely generated free modules` over a commutative ring: the condition being that the ideal generated by the minors of order $n$ is *faithful*, i.e. its annihilator is $0$.

Comment: By sub-determinants do you mean the minors?

Comment: @Sam: $ $Exactly.

Comment: Thank you! I've never studied exterior powers, but the sub-determinant rule I can work with. :)

Answer (score 2):

Recall that for a linear map $T:V\to W$, the *[rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)* states that
$$
\dim\DeclareMathOperator{image}{image}\image(T)+\dim\ker(T)=\dim(V)
$$
Also recall that $T$ is one-to-one [if and only if](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linear_Transformation_is_Injective_iff_Kernel_Contains_Only_Zero) $\dim\ker(T)=0$.

Now, let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and suppose our $T$ is the linear map $T:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ given by $T(x)=Ax$. Then [$\dim\image(T)=\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Alternative_definitions) so the rank-nullity theorem takes the form
$$
\rank(A)+\dim\ker(T)=\dim(\Bbb R^n)
$$
which can be rearranged as
$$
\dim\ker(T)=n-\rank(A)
$$
This gives a satisfying answer to your question:

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Then the linear map $T:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ given by $T(x)=Ax$ is one-to-one if and only if $\rank(A)=n$.

Equivalently:

> Let $A$ be a matrix. Then the linear map given by $T(x)=Ax$ is one-to-one if and only if $\rank(A)=\#\DeclareMathOperator{columns}{columns}\columns(A)$.

Let's test this with your example. Let
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row-reducing gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence $\rank(A)=2<3=\#\columns(A)$. This proves that the linear map $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^4$ given by $T(x)=Ax$ is *not* one-to-one.

Note that in the special case that $A$ is square our result can be restated in terms of determinants, using the fact that $\rank(A)=\#\columns(A)$ if and only if $\det(A)\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

You matrix (let's name it) $A$ represents a linear map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$. For $\phi$ to be one-to-one in particular it has to be onto. But since we have $m \geq n$ and the image of a n-dimensional vector space is itself a vector space of dimension $\leq n$ the map cannot be onto.

Here I'm supposing you are working with real vector spaces (but there is no difference in this respect using other fiels).

Comment: So because it cannot be onto, it is therefore not one-to-one?

Comment: @Alessandro One-to-one does not imply onto.  One-to-one means injective.  Onto means surjective.  They are completely distinct -- meaning neither implies the other.  You're thinking of a one-to-one correspondence (AKA a bijection).  I realize the names are confusingly similar, but if you don't see the word correspondence, one-to-one just means injective.

Comment: Yes. To me one-to-one means both injective and onto (wikipedia distinguishes between "one-to-one function" and "one-to-one correspondence" here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). But if you just want to check if the map is injective as suggested by Bernard you have to show that there is a 3x3 submatrix which determinant is not zero.
@gotit--thanks you are right. I had a slight confusion due to the language, sorry

Comment: Thank you ! You are all very helpful